# Logging in a Python project with multiple points of entry

Tags: python, logging

In a multi-module Python environment, the docs recommend that one run the following snippet in the first point of entry into the Python project to define project-wide logging.

```
# ABC.py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='master.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Start Logging.')
```

If some other file is another potential first point of entry into the project, do I add the same snippet to the top of that file as well? What I am trying to achieve is to specify logging in a single central location regardless of which file is the first point of entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a dedicated python script file just for setting up the logging. Basically, that file would contain exactly what your `ABC.py` file contains now.

Then just import this file in every script that's a potential "entry point". Even if the file is imported twice, the code in the file will be run exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Common approach would be to use module-level loggers.

In your "main" configure logging:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='master.log', level=logging.INFO)
main()
```

In every module use module-level loggers. Each log created that way will use common config:

```
import logging
# my.module.name is arbitrary string and logger identifier, usually it's each module name
logger = logging.getLogger("my.module.name")
logger.info("info msg")
```

Comment: is `module_name` the name of the "main" module? Please explain better